# JFileChooser not 'highlighting' and filtering documents

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

When I run the code below, `filechooser` opens fine, however all the documents are not "highlighted" and I am unable to select them without double clicking. [Please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V604U.png) Adding a filter for only txt files also doesn't work.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
fc.setDialogTitle("choose input file");
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES","txt");
fc.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
int result = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
     File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
     String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
     String name = selectedFile.getName();
     open.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Tested your code and it worked for me. Few ideas of what could be the issue: 1. You only add a file filter to the list, but not actually set it. If you want txt to be the selected filter, call `fc.setFileFilter(filter);`. 2. While the filter filters existing files, it does not automatically add the extension the file you create. If that doesn't help, it may also be a Mac only issue, in which case I cannot help. 3. For not being able to select files: check if you are blocking the AWT Thread anywhere (by doing performance heavy stuff in action listeners)

Comment: I would also check the documentation for the `setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(boolean)` method of `JFileChooser` since `setFileFilter()` does not disable the all-file filter (if that is desired)